# RAILS : uninitialized constant PhotosController::Photo [Ruby on rails]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, controller

He, I have a problem with my code and I'm looking for a solution for 2 hours now. I'm new on ruby on rails ( and rails .. ) and I have this error : 
NameError in PhotosController#new 
uninitialized constant PhotosController::Photo

here my code so you can help me on it !

**photos_controller.rb :**

```
 class PhotosController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_photo, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /photos
  # GET /photos.json
  def index
    @photos = Photo.all 
  end

  # GET /photos/1
  # GET /photos/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /photos/new
  def new
    @photo = Photo.new
  end

  # GET /photos/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /photos
  # POST /photos.json
  def create
    @photo = Photo.new(photo_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @photo.save
        format.html { redirect_to @photo, notice: 'Photo was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @photo }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @photo.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /photos/1
  # PATCH/PUT /photos/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @photo.update(photo_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @photo, notice: 'Photo was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @photo.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /photos/1
  # DELETE /photos/1.json
  def destroy
    @photo.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to photos_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_photo
      @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def photo_params
      params.require(:photo).permit(:image)
    end
end
```

**photo.rb :**

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
has_attached_file :image
end
```

The page I temp to reach ( //.../photos/new ) : 
**new.html.erb :**

```
<h1>New photo</h1>
```

and my route file :

```
PYL::Application.routes.draw do
  get "photos/test"
  get "photos/update"
  get "photos/show"
  get "photos/new"
  resources :photos
  get "photos/new"
  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
   root 'photo#index'

  # Example of regular route:
  #   get 'products/:id' => 'catalog#view'

  # Example of named route that can be invoked with purchase_url(id: product.id)
  #   get 'products/:id/purchase' => 'catalog#purchase', as: :purchase

  # Example resource route (maps HTTP verbs to controller actions automatically):
  #   resources :products

  # Example resource route with options:
  #   resources :products do
  #     member do
  #       get 'short'
  #       post 'toggle'
  #     end
  #
  #     collection do
  #       get 'sold'
  #     end
  #   end

  # Example resource route with sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments, :sales
  #     resource :seller
  #   end

  # Example resource route with more complex sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments
  #     resources :sales do
  #       get 'recent', on: :collection
  #     end
  #   end

  # Example resource route with concerns:
  #   concern :toggleable do
  #     post 'toggle'
  #   end
  #   resources :posts, concerns: :toggleable
  #   resources :photos, concerns: :toggleable

  # Example resource route within a namespace:
  #   namespace :admin do
  #     # Directs /admin/products/* to Admin::ProductsController
  #     # (app/controllers/admin/products_controller.rb)
  #     resources :products
  #   end
end
```

If you have an idea, please help me :)

Comment: Edit your model name, it should be singular Photo...http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/naming-conventions-for-ruby-on-rails.html

Comment: I changed it but it didn't solve my problem !

Comment: The model file name should also be photo.rb and class Photo should be used inside it

Comment: It's find now thank's. I put the photo.rb file in the wrong folder by mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You named your model class `Photos` instead of `Photo`. It should be:

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :image
end
```

Comment: @user3028968 where is your photo.rb file placed?

Comment: Oh ! Sorry ! It's was not in the good folder. I put it by mistake in a bad one ! Now it is in the Model folder and every things is find. Thank you !